# How can i create bucket and post xml file on aws s3 using vc++

Tags: visual-c++

How can i create bucket and post xml file on aws s3  using vc++.
Thanks 
dabara

Answer (score 0):

Use C++/CLI (i.e. VC++ targeting the .NET CLR), and the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) ([docs here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html)).  In particular see the Amazon.S3 namespace and the AmazonS3Client.PutBucket and PutObject methods.

Comment: Thanks itowlson for reply but i need a solution in vc++.

Comment: Just to clarify, C++/CLI is part of VC++.  Do you strictly need a solution in unmanaged C++?  If so let me know and I'll delete the answer -- thanks!